# Angular 14 error: Nested CSS was detected, but CSS nesting has not been configured correctly

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css

I have some nested css in one of my component's css files. When I do 'ng serve' the css does not work and I get this error:

`(11:5) Nested CSS was detected, but CSS nesting has not been configured correctly. Please enable a CSS nesting plugin *before* Tailwind in your configuration. See how here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting`

This is a fresh project created with angular CLI 14, with tailwind installed according to instructions here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/angular

I have tried adding the postcss.config.js file to my project as specified in the link provided by the error, but nothing appears to happen:

```
    module.exports = {
      plugins: {
        'postcss-import': {},
        'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue when using tailwind with SCSS, I solved the problem by removing the following import from my `styles.scss` file:

```
@import url('./styles/utility.scss');
```

Since `url` is CSS specific syntax, my guess is that tailwind (or postcss to be precise) thinks the file within the parenthesis will always be a CSS file. So as soon as it encounters nesting, it throws that error.

Solved by using the @use syntax which SCSS prescribe when importing CSS:
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use/